# fancyhead: how to add second image on header

Tags: graphics, header-footer, positioning

I would add a second (and maybe third) image on my header, made by this command:

```
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=39mm]{%
           banner_a.png}
```

Can I and how, insert a second image at left of `banner_a.png` (and maybe also another one at right).

I would add at the same vertical position, more left or right that `banner_a.png`.

Comment: what I’ve made to obtain -2 and no answer?

Comment: You've been a member this long, and asked that many questions, and can't make a minimal working example with what you've tried.  And the code that you did post has an unclosed `{`.  You're using fancyhdr, so that documentation should tell you how to do what you're wanting to do.

Comment: You can put multiple `\includegraphics` commands next to each other inside `\fancyhead`. If necessary separate them by some `\hspace{...}`.